# How to access ExtJS-Variable in Shopware template?

Tags: templates, extjs, shopware

there is a problem I can not get my head around working on a plugin for shopware 5.

That's what I am working on (its my own shopping world element).

1. I defined my own xtype.
2. Within that xtype class declaration, I added a field with the help of ExtJS that already exists (CategorySelection). This field is also used in the shoppingworld environment.
3. All existent Categories (and subcategories) are listed when I drag my own shoppingworld element in the grid and edit the config (pencil symbol).

My problem is:
How can I display the selected category in my frontend template?
How can I save the selected category to display it again when I want to edit the configuration?

With smarty and {debug} I am able to see what variables I can access in my template.
In the $data-Variable for example, I can see variables I added with the help of $component->createMediaField(...)-methods.

I figured know that that one possible option would be assign a variable to the view in the subscriber ($args->getView()->assign('catSeleted', $catSelected)).

Is this the correct way to do it, and if so, how can I access the ExtJS-component get the selected element?

I know it is a basic question, but I can't figure it out.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem, you save some data and want to show it in frontend for customers?

Comment: Hi @alexeypalamar,

thanks for your reply. You are right.

Via $component->addMediaField() I can set a picture in the backend (shopping world element) as a banner, and the the file manager is automatically loaded.
Via Ext.JS and the CategorySelection-element I want to display the selected category. The field is displayed and all categories are shown.

In the end, I want to put the name of the selected category on the banner . Thats what my plugin is supossed to do. 

The customer shouldsee the banner with additional text of the shopping world element as the shop owner configured it.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know what is`$component->addMediaField() `.. It isn't something standart. Maybe you create attribute with Media for emotion? Maybe you can add some code samples or link to Git where I can see it?

Comment: I got this from the developer page
(https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/plugin-system/#minimal-plugin-example)

Comment: Search for this code part: "$vimeoElement->createTextField".
$vimeoElement is what I call $component.

In my .tpl-file, I can access the field via {$Data.vimeo_video_id} and the value of that text field will be printed.

Comment: Am I right understand your problem is: you got int `id`, but you need to fetch link to source for display link `<img src="{$pathThere}">`?

Comment: You are right. I actually got <img src="{$Data.imglink}"/> working, since I can find the variable is in my template variables (smarty debug).
I now need to figure out how to add an extjs-variable to my template variables, since the category-field is added via extjs and not via "->addTextfiel()".

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand you problem.. ExtJs have no any relations with front-end, you need to describe what you try to get. You create emotion with image, got path for this image, what problem now?

Comment: But you can use ExtJS to create parts of your config of an emotion for  the shopbacked, right?
xtype-creation is ExtJS extending from base etc... 
When I then configure my emotion, I need to read the config out of my ExtJS-Element to be able to put it in my template vars (so that I can access the data in my frontend template).

Comment: By frontend template you mean template which will see customers in frontend of your store or .tpl in backend for admin?

Comment: A template that customers will see and which I can debug with chrome dev tools.

Comment: Sorry, I need to see your code for I can help

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate your help and effort, @Alexey Palamar.
I finally got it to work, without the ExtJS though.
Instead creating fields mit ExtJS I used the fields provided by shopware.
See https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/custom-shopping-world-elements/.